# Access denied calling EnumJobs

Tags: windows, winapi, printers

I'm trying to get the domain username of jobs in a printer queue on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard.  Code snippet below is in Delphi. OpenPrinter and EnumJobs are part of the Windows Spooler API.

**Update!**  Setting maxJobs to a higher multiple of 4 allows for more jobs in the queue to be enumerated.  eg.  Setting maxJobs=8 allows for two jobs, but not three.  maxJobs=12 allows for three jobs.

**Solved!** It looks like I can just ignore the return value of EnumJobs, and simply see if the number of jobs it returns > 0 (the last argument when calling).  This seems to work fine for all instances listed below, including printer via a share.

```
const
  maxJobs = 4;
var
  h : THandle;
  jia : array [1..maxJobs] of JOB_INFO_1;
  jiz, jic : DWord;  // size of jia, count of jia
begin
  if OpenPrinter('DocTest', h, nil) then
  begin
    if EnumJobs(h, 0, maxJobs, 1, @jia, SizeOf(jia), jiz, jic) then  
[...]
```

EnumJobs returns true or false depending on different conditions listed below.  If it returns false in any of the following situations, the error message I'm retrieving is "System Error.  Code: 5.  Access is denied".

Clearly a permissions problem.  I have assigned Print, Manage this Printer, and Manage documents to Everyone in the printer security settings.  All jobs have been submitted after those settings have been assigned.  My program is running in a session logged in as the domain administrator.

- EnumJobs returns TRUE if I print a job from the same session I'm running this program in, and there's only one job in the queue. (See Update above for change)
- EnumJobs returns TRUE if I print from another session on the server (it has terminal services installed) as any user, and there's only one job in the queue.  (See Update above for change)
- EnumJobs returns FALSE if there is more than one job in the queue. It doesn't matter if the jobs are for the same user or not.  (See Update above for change)
- EnumJobs returns FALSE if I print a job from another server to the printer share.  Both servers are in the same domain.  It doesn't matter which user prints the job, including the domain administrator.

What's going on here, in particular getting an access denied when enumerating more than (maxJobs / 4) job(s) at a time?

Comment: Did the the program has the access to the `C:\Windows\System32\spool` directory?

Comment: @Drake it does, it's running as a domain administrator after all.  After getting the job info above, it scans the job content in the spool folder's *.spl file to get more information before deleting the job.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the return value of EnumJobs and inspect the out argument pcReturned to see if it's greater than 0.  This indicates the number of print jobs found.